# How to paste (like R) and groupby in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am having trouble converting an R code example to my script and was wondering how to achieve the same.

```
product_df <- example_df[,paste(name, collapse="_"),by=product_id]
```

I found this code snippet on the a previous SO question but it was just concatenating everything together and not by a specific ID.

```
import functools
def reduce_concat(x, sep=""):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + sep + str(y), x)

def paste(*lists, sep=" ", collapse=None):
    result = map(lambda x: reduce_concat(x, sep=sep), zip(*lists))
    if collapse is not None:
        return reduce_concat(result, sep=collapse)
    return list(result)
```

Here is the code to produce the original Dataframe below

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'product_id': ['100_1244', '100_1244', '100_1244', '100_1244', '200_1244', '200_1244', '200_1244', '200_1244'],
                      'name': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange']})

    product_id  name
0   100_1244    apple
1   100_1244    apple
2   100_1244    apple
3   100_1244    apple
4   200_1244    orange
5   200_1244    orange
6   200_1244    orange 
7   200_1244    orange
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
    product_id  name
0   100_1244    apple_apple_apple_apple
1   200_1244    orange_orange_orange_orange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby` with `join`

```
df.groupby('product_id').apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x['name']))

product_id
100_1244        apple_apple_apple_apple
200_1244    orange_orange_orange_orange
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that simple and elegant answer really appriciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You may check with `groupby`

```
example_df.groupby('product_id').name.apply('_'.join).reset_index()

  product_id                         name
0   100_1244      apple_apple_apple_apple
1   200_1244  orange_orange_orange_orange
```